# Kotlin recursive function to compare two array and keep the content of origin array

Tags: kotlin

I need to compare two MutableList, requiredDevices and providedDevices using recursive function. These two MutableList is the element of a MutableList, originalArray as well. If there is a match, it will take out the matched element of requiredDevices and providedDevices, one by one, and add the leftover to list1 and list2, respectively. How can I do this and keep the content of requiredDevices and providedDevices and originalArray . For example:

```
originalArray=[requiredDevices, providedDevices]
           =[["A","B","C"],["B,"C","A","A","D"]]

requiredDevices=["A","B","C"]
providedDevices=["B,"C","A","A","D"]
```

, after the recursion:

```
list1=[] (empty array)
list2=["A","D"]

originalArray=[[],["A","D"]]
```

Tried to write a recursive function and take requiredDevices and providedDevices as argument. The recursive function returns a list temp contains list1 and list2. But requiredDevices and providedDevices is modified as well.

```
val temp = mutableListOf<MutableList<String>>()
fun compareArray(requiredDevices: MutableList<String>, providedDevices: MutableList<String>): List<MutableList<String>> {

    for (i in 1 until requiredDevices.size) {
        for (j in 0 until providedDevices.size) {

            try {
                if (requiredDevices[i] == providedDevices[j]) {
                    requiredDevices.removeAt(i)
                    providedDevices.removeAt(j)

                    compareArray(requiredDevices, providedDevices)

                    temp.add(requiredDevices)
                    temp.add(providedDevices)
                }
            } catch (e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
            }
        }
    }

    return temp.distinct()
}
```

I want to keep the originalArray content and still get the same result of list1 and list2. As following:

```
originalArray=[["A","B","C"],["B,"C","A","D"]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really follow what your algorithm is trying to do. Based on your comment, I think this solves the problem. This copies the two starting lists into new lists, and then removes items from the copies one-by-one, so they will retain excess items if they have them.

```
fun <T> removeCommonValues(listA: List<T>, listB: List<T>): Pair<List<T>, List<T>> {
    val outA = listA.toMutableList()
    val outB = listB.toMutableList()
    for (i in (outA.size - 1) downTo 0){
        for (j in (outB.size - 1) downTo 0){
            if (outA[i] == outB[j]){
                outA.removeAt(i)
                outB.removeAt(j)
                break
            }
        }
    }

    return outA to outB
}
```

Test:

```
fun main() {
    val required = listOf("A", "B", "C", "C")
    val available = listOf("B", "C", "A", "D", "D")
    println(removeCommonValues(required, available))
}

// Outputs ([C], [D, D])
```

Comment: I didn't use filter because I want to take out matched element one by one. listA has only one A but it can take out all A in listB. I want 1 A takes out 1 A only.

Comment: See edit. I didn't understand all the needs. You can iterate the intersection repeatedly, and `remove` just removes one at a time.

Comment: Thanks alot. In the beginning I thought I'd have to use recursion to solve it, that's why I add it in the question's title. Didn't know the problem can be solved without using it.